# What certifications do I need to become a Malware Analyst?

Tags: professional-education, certification

I've previously posted here on how to get started as a malware analyst, and wanted to say thanks on getting me started.

How much do certifications help me on my resume and which one(s) should I get? Will experience ultimately be better than a cert? And finally, when should I get certified? I'm currently a sophomore studying information assurance, should I wait until I graduate to get certified?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer here is that experience is the only thing that matter. Reverse engineer tons of stuff. Expand your knowledge. Share what you've learned. Etc etc.

But of course, getting a certification won't do you any harm and as far as I am concerned, will only count as a plus on your CV.

However; having a certification on your CV doesn't get you a job on it's own. In today's day and age the recruiters are actively searching for people who "do more". I would suggest that you start building your "brand". Make yourself visible in the community. Discuss new malware on Twitter. Share your knowledge here on security.SE etc. That's what ultimately is going to secure your position as a malware analyst.

When it comes to what certs to take; I've heard and read a lot of good things about the [GIAC Reverse Engineering Malware (GREM)](http://www.giac.org/certification/reverse-engineering-malware-grem) certification.

I've also been looking at a lot of open Malware Analyst positions, and here are some of the varous certifications they ask for. There are probably many more, and these are usually just suggestions from the hiring-side. Don't be afraid if your certification isn't on their "we want someone with these certs"-list, they might just not have concidered (or hear of) the one you have (which isn't necessarily a bad thing, HR is HR after all).

- [GIAC Reverse Engineering Malware (GREM)](http://www.giac.org/certification/reverse-engineering-malware-grem)
- [Microsoft Certified Solutions Expert (MCSE)](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcse-certification.aspx)
- [Cisco Certified Network Associate (CCNA)](http://www.cisco.com/web/learning/certifications/associate/ccna/index.html)
- [Cisco Certified Network Professional (CCNP)](http://www.cisco.com/web/learning/certifications/professional/ccnp/index.html)
- [Certified Information Systems Security Professional (CISSP)](https://www.isc2.org/cissp/default.aspx)
- [Certified Ethical Hacker (CEH)](http://www.eccouncil.org/Certification/certified-ethical-hacker)
- [Certified Authorization Professional (CAP)](https://www.isc2.org/cap)

For your last question; Take a certification when you have the money, time and done enough research on the certification to make you certain that it covers exactly what you want to learn. There is no rush, and some employers even pay for certifications once your hired. So my best suggestion is, start building your brand and grow your knownledge.

Answer (score 0):

The certifications you need are the ones your employer is looking for. There is no better gauge than that.

As for when you you get them: you get them when you deserve them. When you are ready to write, you write, and not before. To cram for an exam and memorize answers, you do yourself a disservice. Certs are *one* way to show your experience after you have already achieved your experience. Experience trumps certs every time.

Sophomore? It doesn't matter - if you're ready, you can write them in Kindergarten.

That said, there is a valid use case where you study for certifications in order to guide your study in the topic, but the goal is the same: the cert shows your wider experience.